# Quite possibly a stupid and long authentication question

Tags: sql-server-2012, authentication

First off, I am not remotely a DBA.  But I'm basically responsible for the application and we don't have a DBA, so here I am.  There's two separate errors that may be related but occur at separate times.  We have an application (Solarwinds) which has 12 servers that connect back to the SQL Server (11.0.6248) using SQL Authentication.  99.9% of the time it works fine.  Then, randomly out of the blue the following issues occur (issues occur at separate times).

### Issue 1

Login failed for user 'username'.  Reason:  Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT:  ipaddress]
Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 5.

Username is the SQL account that all 12 servers are using, and have been using for ages.  Password hasn't changed.  Client is always the "main" application server (Primary poller in Solarwinds terms).  At that point the application does a crash and burn.  Restart servers and it's back up and everything is fine until it does it again.  This happens once or twice a month.

The credentials the application use to connect are obviously good as it works the other 99% of the time.  If you're not familiar with the application it's doing real time server and application monitoring so there's constantly data being written to it.  There's nothing else installed on the application server the error points to nor are there any other databases on the SQL server.  Both boxes are dedicated to this application.

### Issue 2

Again, out of the blue, application has been running fine.

Login Failed for user 'username'.  Reason:  Access to server validation failed while revalidating the login on the connection.  [CLIENT: ipaddress]
Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 23.

So far all my Googlefu has found for that error references specifically SQL Server 2005 and a hotfix for the issue.  As mentioned above, we're running SQL Server 2012.  As with the other error, this occurs out of the blue at random times and again, restart services, and everything going back to functioning normally.

What am I missing here?  The vendor says it's not an application issue and I see nothing to dispute that.  It's safe to assume SQL Server isn't setup remotely close to anything resembling best practices but I don't know where to start with that.

Comment: Not a stupid question. Sounds like a nasty problem and a great puzzle at the same time.

Comment: When you say application do you mean solar winds? I wouldn't trust that it isn't a solar winds issue. Have you upgraded to the latest version of Solarwinds? We experienced an issue where we were unable to register / reconnect to one of our monitored instances after it (the monitored instance application) was upgraded. The odd thing is only the application was upgraded, not the db we were monitoring. After upgrading to DPA 11.0.378 we were able to register and monitor this instance again. We still don't know the root problem, and I know this sounds like a "restart the server to fix it" solution

Comment: Yes.  I've spent hours on the phone with their tier 3 support and application developers.  Once it tanks, we can verify it's not Solarwinds as you can't connect to the DB outside of Solarwinds either.  We built a new Solarwinds farm back in Sept with the latest version at the time (12.0).  We installed the latest (at the time) hotfixes (12.0.1) in December.  At this time we are one hotfix behind, but as stated above it doesn't seem to be an issue on the Solarwinds side.  We aren't running DPA, but we are running basically everything else.  NPM, NCM, SAM, VNQM, IPAM, etc.

Comment: Which "Services" do you have to restart to recover from this?

Comment: Sorry, but I thought I'd already replied to this.  SQL Server.  Just tanked again, prompting me to check the thread for updates.  Managed to go 10 days without having to reboot SQL.